# How to remove unseen style element from html tag

Tags: php, html, nan, hidden

I am webscraping a website and I am having difficulty with one item.

```
$coprp = split_string($coprp, "<td id=\"p\" class=\"datatable-item\">",AFTER,EXCL);
$coprp = split_string($coprp, "td id=\"nch\"", BEFORE, EXCL);
$coprp = strip_tags($coprp);
$coprp = trim($coprp);
$coprp= str_split($coprp,100);
$commd[2] = $coprp[0];
```

the target line is:

```
td id="p" class="datatable-item" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">3.7624</td
```

The problem is I can get the 3.7624 and display it but I can not put it into an array for numbers because it has this style elementattached that is unseen in the regular html.

Is there a simple direct way to remove this unseen line using PHP?

Comment: To remove what? The whole line or the style or you just need to change the background color?

Comment: For scraping, you should use DOMDocument class in PHP. Also, if anything gets added later while scraping, it might be some javascript snippets doing so!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, your tag should be:

```
<td id="p" class="datatable-item" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">3.7624</td>
```

In PHP, to get the data from a td tag, you can use DOMDocument

This is a working code:

```
<?php
$html='<td id="p" class="datatable-item" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">3.7624</td>';
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHtml($html);
$x = new DOMXpath($dom);
foreach($x->query('//td') as $td){

    echo $td->textContent;

}
```

On execution you will be `3.7624` (without style element)